# How to create links to change textbox value using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I am trying to use Javascript to create links to change the textbox value?

What am I missing?

This is what I have so far.

```
createLink("A");
createLink("B");
createLink("C");
createLink("D");

function createLink(queueName) {
    var a = document.createElement("a"); // Create a <a> node
    a.innerHTML = queueName;
    a.title = queueName;
    a.style.marginLeft = "5px";
    a.href = "javascript:void(0);";
    a.onClick = function () {
        replace();
    };
    document.getElementById('newOwn_top').appendChild(a);
}

function replace() {
    document.getElementById("newOwn_mlktp").selectedIndex = 1;
    document.getElementById("newOwn").value = "a";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y0qsvxes/

Comment: I highly don't recommend you write so much JavaScript inside an HTML attribute, it's not good practice. Also how would these links change the value? Would clicking `A` append the letter "A" to the textbox, and the same for `B` appending "B"?

Comment: `a.onClick` should be `a.onclick`, that will make the click event work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
a.onClick = function() {
    replace();
};
```

to:

```
a.onclick = function() {
    replace();
};
```

You can get away with the mixed case in HTML attributes, but Javascript properties are case-sensitive.

```js
createLink("A");
createLink("B");
createLink("C");
createLink("D");

function createLink(queueName) {
    var a = document.createElement("a"); // Create a <a> node
    a.innerHTML = queueName;
    a.title = queueName;
    a.style.marginLeft = "5px";
    a.href = "javascript:void(0);";
    a.onclick = function () {
        replace();
    };
    document.getElementById('newOwn_top').appendChild(a);
}

function replace() {
    document.getElementById("newOwn_mlktp").selectedIndex = 1;
    document.getElementById("newOwn").value = "a";
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td class="data2Col" colspan="3">
        <div class="requiredInput">
            <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
            <div id="newOwn_top" name="newOwn_top" style="white-space: nowrap">
                <select id="newOwn_mlktp" name="newOwn_mlktp" onchange="LookupAutoCompleteInputElement.handleLookupTypeChange('newOwn',false);if 
(getElementById('newOwn_lktp').value.search('queue') < 0 &amp;&amp; 
false) {
    getElementByIdCS('sendMail').checked = true; 
} else {
    getElementByIdCS('sendMail').checked = false;
}" title="Search scope">
                    <option value="005" selected="selected">User</option>
                    <option value="case_queue">Queue</option>
                    <option value="PartnerUserLookup">Partner User</option>
                    <option value="NonLpuCustomerSuccessUserLookup">Customer Portal User</option>
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" name="newOwn_lkid" id="newOwn_lkid" value="000000000000000">
                <input type="hidden" name="newOwn_lkold" id="newOwn_lkold" value="null">
                <input type="hidden" name="newOwn_lktp" id="newOwn_lktp" value="StandardUserLookup">
                <input type="hidden" name="newOwn_lspf" id="newOwn_lspf" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" name="newOwn_lspfsub" id="newOwn_lspfsub" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" name="newOwn_mod" id="newOwn_mod" value="0"><span class="lookupInput"><input id="newOwn" maxlength="255" name="newOwn" onchange="getElementByIdCS('newOwn_lkid').value='';getElementByIdCS('newOwn_mod').value='1';" size="20" title="Owner name" type="text"><a href="javascript:%20openLookup%28%27%2F_ui%2Fcommon%2Fdata%2FLookupPage%3Flkfm%3DeditPage%26lknm%3DnewOwn%26lktp%3D%27%20%2B%20getElementByIdCS%28%27newOwn_lktp%27%29.value%2C670%2C%271%27%2C%27%26lksrch%3D%27%20%2B%20escapeUTF%28getElementByIdCS%28%27newOwn%27%29.value.substring%280%2C%2080%29%29%29" id="newOwn_lkwgt" onclick="setLastMousePosition(event)" secid="newOwn_mlbtn" title="Owner name"></a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If that's it then this question should probably be closed as a typographical error.

Comment: I thought about that, but it seems like this is more of a misunderstanding than just a typo. There are many places where Javascript uses camelCase, but this isn't one of them.